# Serializing JSON wraps string in escaped quotation marks

Tags: json, playframework

When serialising a case class to Json I get the following strange behaviour that I haven't encountered to date:

```
Record(12345,List(Values("foo_baz"), Values("foo_bar")))
=> {"_id":"12345","values":[{"value":"\"foo_baz\""},{"value":"\"foo_bar\""}]}
```

Here is the case class:

```
final case class Record(userId: UserId, values: List[Values])

object Record {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Record]
}
```

And the nested `Values` case class:

```
case class Values(value: String)

object Values {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Values]
}
```

*Edit*

Played around in a worksheet:

```
Json.toJson(Record(UserId("1234"),List(Values("foo_bar"), Values("foo_bar"))))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"_id":"1234","values":[{"value":"foo_bar"},{"value":"foo_bar"}]}
```

At my application point:

```
  def insert(in: Record) =
  {
    println(in)
    println(toJson(in))
    collection.insertIfNoneMatch(
      Json.obj("_id" -> in.userId), toJson(in))
      .map(_.map(_.as[Record]))
  }
```

Results of println's :

```
Record(1234,List(Values("foo_bar"), Values("foo_bar")))
{"_id":"jQC1v7m2RnyRoS7Y5goTSQ","values":[{"value":"\"foo_bar\""},  {"value":"\"foo_bar\""}]}
```

Comment: Where does `Permission` come from? Is that supposed to be `Values`? And I do not see this behaviour. Play version?

Comment: Yes `Values` sorry. The version is `2.3.7`.

Comment: I added some debugs in my application and there's some strange behaviour. In a worksheet it works fine, however when println'ing from the application it adds the escaped quotation marks.

Comment: I suspect this is a tooling issue. I do not see it in a Scala console: `scala> Json.toJson(Record(12345,List(Values("foo_baz"), Values("foo_bar"))))
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"userId":12345,"values":[{"value":"foo_baz"},{"value":"foo_bar"}]}`

Comment: Are you sure your `Values` contents aren't getting already pre-quoted? The result of a case class auto-generated `toString` should not include quotes around the strings. Your println debug does, which suggests the issue is with the data input, not the JSON serialization.

Comment: Ah found the problem. In the data input case class I was calling `.toString()` on the value fields. I changed it to `.validateString]` and it works. Thanks a lot!